# Functor instance for GADTs

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement the Functor instance for a GADT in order to experiment with the The Constrained-Monad Problem paper. So far my code is this

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Expr a where
  I   :: Int -> Expr Int
  B   :: Bool -> Expr Bool
  Add :: Expr Int -> Expr Int->Expr Int
  Mul :: Expr Int -> Expr Int->Expr Int
  Eq  :: Eq a => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool

data ExprF a where
  Fmap :: (a->b) -> Expr a -> ExprF b

instance Functor ExprF where
  fmap f (Fmap g e) = Fmap (f . g ) e

liftExpr :: Expr a -> ExprF a
liftExpr = Fmap id

unliftExprF :: ExprF a-> Expr a
unliftExprF (Fmap f e) = e

eval :: Eq a => Expr a-> a
eval a =
  case a of
   I i -> i
   B b -> b
   Add a b -> eval a + eval b
   Mul a b -> eval a * eval b
   Eq a b -> (eval a) == (eval b)

eval2 :: Eq a => Expr a-> (a->b) -> b
eval2 a f = f $ eval a

class Reval a where
   reval :: a-> Expr a

instance Reval Int where
   reval i =  I i

instance Reval Bool where
   reval b = B b
```

The `ExprF` type is to overcome the `Eq` constraint. The `Reval` typeclass is in order to construct a `Expr` from a value because I cannot pattern match on primitive types(Int,Bool) I couldn't find any better way. `liftExpr` creates `ExprF` from an `Expr`. And the problem is the `unliftExprF` because  does not typecheck. Although it seems logical to me. The aforementioned paper tells something about the Functor problem but it uses ConstraintKinds.
I also I know that I could use the Rmonad package but I want to try something myself. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What would you expect the result of `unliftExprF (Fmap show (I 3))` to be?

Comment: Your `ExprF` is just a special case of `Data.Functor.Coyoneda`. `data Coyoneda :: (Type -> Type) -> Type -> Type where Coyoneda :: (a -> b) -> f a -> Coyoneda f b`. You can't `lowerCoyoneda` unless you have a `Functor`. One option is to add an `Fmap :: (a -> b) -> Expr a -> Expr b` constructor, which will let you write `instance Functor Expr where fmap = Fmap`. This is only lawful, however, if you only care about how `Expr`s `eval`, and not about their structures.

Comment: Side note: your language currently contains *only* `Eq` types, so your `Eq` constraint is redundant. You could leave it out and write `data Tag a where IntTag :: Tag Int; BoolTag :: Tag Bool` `typeOf :: Expr a -> Tag a` (obvious non-recursive implementation). Then when you `eval` an `Eq`, you can `typeOf` its first argument and match on that to reveal the `Eq` instance of the arguments.

Comment: If we could make `unliftExprF` work, we could implement an `instance Functor Expr`. But that would imply that we can create, say, `Expr ()` values, which is impossible.

Comment: @dfeuer yes, but adding constructors like `Fmap` is usually a rabbit hole you should think about carefully before you go down.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, yes, it's probably not what this problem actually needs.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't really read your code very carefully before writing the answer below. Actually, the way you set it up it seems the `ExprF` type shouldn't need any special handling at all, because that is simply a `Coyoneda`, i.e. you forcibly pull your structure into the `Hask` (or, conceptually, **Set**) category. As such, your `Functor` instance works just fine, but **`unliftExprF` is impossible to implement**. You could however ignore this and simply use

```
eval' :: ExprF a -> a
eval' (ExprF f x) = f $ eval x
```

---

### Original answer

If your data type can logically contain only `Eq` values, it just doesn't make sense for it to be a `Prelude.Functor` instance. You could perhaps hack your way around this with extra constructors, but it's going to be a mess and will make the data type nearly unusable because you always bump into a constructor that hides the actual structure behind a function that first requires an input value before you can do anything more.
(I should know, I've dabbled with GADTs like that a number of times.)

Instead, you should just restrict yourself to an `fmap` corresponding to a category that only allows the values that actually make sense for this structure, i.e. basically

```
class FunctorEq f where
  fmapEq :: (Eq a, Eq b) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

There are a number of classes available that cover this general need.

- With [constraint-classes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraint-classes-0.5.1/docs/Control-ConstraintClasses.html):

  ```
  {-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

  import Control.ConstraintClasses

  type instance Dom Expr a = Eq a

  instance CFunctor Expr where
    _fmap = ...
  ```
- With [constrained-categories](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.4.1.0/docs/Control-Category-Constrained.html)

  ```
  import qualified Prelude as Hask
  import Control.Category.Constrained.Prelude

  instance Functor Expr (Eq⊢(->)) (Eq⊢(->)) where
    fmap = ...
  ```

  Then you'll need e.g. `` fmap (constrained (*2)) $ I 4`Add`I 5 ``. (Note that this is the [`$` operator](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.4.1.0/docs/Control-Arrow-Constrained.html#v:-36-) from `Control.Arrow.Constrained`.)

I would recommend using `constrained-categories`, because it has a disciplined way of defining not only functors in constrained categories, but also more category-theory concepts that are necessary for *generating* expressions in a lambda-calculus like sublanguage. But as the author of that library, I'm biased...

Comment: [`rmonad`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rmonad-0.8.0.2), which you've already noticed, should work too, but I think this package is obsolete.

Comment: This particular type needs more than `Eq`; it needs `IsIntOrBool`. And `fmap`, in this case, only needs the constraint on the result type. `fmap :: IsIntOrBool b => (a -> b) -> Expr a -> Expr b`. But the fact that `fmap` needs to "flatten" its argument with `eval` is quite shady. Better to write an evaluation function that preserves the type information.

Answer (score 0):

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForAll #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import GHC.Exts (Constraint)

data Expr a where
 I   :: Int -> Expr Int
 B   :: Bool -> Expr Bool
 Add :: Expr Int -> Expr Int->Expr Int
 Mul :: Expr Int -> Expr Int->Expr Int
 Eq  :: Eq a => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool

data ExprNF :: (* -> Constraint) -> (* -> *) -> * -> * where
  FMap :: Eq x => (x->a) -> Expr x -> ExprNF Eq Expr a

 instance Functor (ExprNF Eq Expr) where
   fmap :: (a->b)->ExprNF Eq Expr a -> ExprNF Eq Expr b
   fmap g (FMap h tx) = FMap (g . h) tx

 liftNF :: Eq a => Expr a -> ExprNF Eq Expr a
 liftNF ta = FMap id ta

 lowerNF :: (forall x . Eq x => (x->a)-> Expr x -> Expr a) -> ExprNF Eq Expr a -> Expr a
 lowerNF fmp (FMap g tx) = fmp g tx
```